# Bound for $\left|\sum_{\substack{1\leq d\leq x\\(d,r)=1}}\frac{G_d}{d^{1+\varepsilon}}\right|$, where $G_d$ denote the Gregory coefficients

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, asymptotics

In this post we denote the Gregory coefficients, or reciprocal logarithmic numbers, this Wikipedia [*Gregory coefficients*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_coefficients) as $G_k$, for integers $k\geq 1$. I would like to know if it is possible to get upper bounds for next two sequences.

> **Question.** We denote the greatest common factor of two positive integers $a\geq 1$ and $b\geq 1$ as $(a,b)$. Provide the calculations (or hints for one of these similar  problems) to get $$\left|\sum_{\substack{1\leq d\leq x\\(d,r)=1}}\frac{G_d}{d^{1+\varepsilon}}\right|\leq \text{upper bound}=\text{upper bound}(\varepsilon,x,r)\tag{1}$$ or for the sequence 
>   $$\left|\sum_{\substack{1\leq d\leq x\\(d,r)=1}}\frac{G_d}{d^{1+\varepsilon}}\log\frac{x}{d}\right|\leq \text{upper bound}=\text{upper bound}(\varepsilon,x,r)\tag{2}$$
>   for reals $\varepsilon>0$ and $x\geq 1$, and integers $r\geq 1$. **Many thanks.**

Here thus $\text{upper bound}(\varepsilon,x,r)$ denotes a suitable function of $\epsilon$, $x$ and $r$, and I'm asking it (if possible/feasible) in the spirit of **Theorem 1.1** and **Theorem 1.2** from [1].

As was said if the calculations are similar, provide the reasonings for one of these problems and if you want hints for the other. Any case, I'm asking about what work can be done for some of these problems.

### References:

[1] Olivier Ramaré, *Some elementary explicit bounds for two mollifications of the Moebius function*, Funct. Approx. Comment. Math. Volume 49, Number 2 (2013), pp 229-240.

Comment: I know the reference from **Project Euclid**.

Comment: I hope that my **Question** is clear, interesting and at research level, please feel free to add your feedback in comments.